# Classifying space of the reals

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

What's the classifying space $B\mathbb{R}$ of the additive group of real numbers provided with the Euclidean topology ?

By the extension $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R} \twoheadrightarrow S^1$ there is a fibration $S^1 \to B\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}P^\infty$. 
But I wonder, if there is an explicit description of $B\mathbb{R}$ ? Has this space a particular name ?

Comment: Even better: If $G$ is a contractible topological group, we may take $EG=G$ with the obvious action and obtain $BG=G/G=\{\ast\}$.

Comment: @Baby Dragon: Thanks for your comment. That answers my question perfectly. Of course you can also post it as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You make a good point that this will continue to work for any contractible group. This raises a question. Is it true that if $G$ is a topological group (with nice enough point set properties) and $BG$ is homotopy equivalent to $G$, then is $G$ contractible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can construct a space, which we will call $EG$ such that our group acts transitively and freely, then we may set $BG=EG/G$. But if we have $\mathbb{R}$ act on $\mathbb{ER}=\mathbb{R}^2$ by $r∗(x,y)=(x+r,y)$, this will do the trick. Thus we get that $B\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$. Their are other models as well.

Comment: Why not take $E\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}$?  What does the $y$ component gain you?

Comment: You are certainly right about that as Ralph's comment indicates. But this was my first approach. Also I find it amusing that the classifying space is the group itself.

Comment: A more serious answer might be that it is a good idea to have thickened models around if one has to do some serious homotopy theory (straightening problems) or if we need a to be able to get inclusions into a model of the homotopy type.

Comment: I see, I had never thought of it from the persepective.